# to archive using cron

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to archive folders using cron.
It work when I start it using terminal, but do not with cron

```
import zipfile
import os
import shutil
from datetime import date
path = "/Users/dimonchik/Documents/photo.png"
date = date.today()


try:
    shutil.make_archive('/Users/dimonchik/Documents/backup/archieve/%s' % date, 'zip', '/Users/dimonchik/Documents/bash/%s' % date)
except OSError:
    pass
```

how start this code with cron?

```
* * * * * python3 /Users/dimonchik/Documents/bash/test.py
```

that is cron code

sorry, if something is wrong, I am using stackoverflow at first

Comment: Maybe this is of help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: I do everything like that, but smth is wrong

Comment: Maybe you could check if cron logs any errors or the execution of your script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log Alternatively, you could log to a file, that your script is running, including if `OSError` is raised.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will check a little bit later